# Centered Enumeration

Tags: errors, positioning

I want a centered enumeration, where the top-level is centered. 
This brings two problems:

1. enumeration stops, and I get the text not counted
2. I get the error "Something's wrong - perhaps a missing \item"

Code used is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \begin{center}
      \item First title
      \item Second title
    \end{center}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Would be awesome if anybody could help me out!

Comment: It looks as if you are misusing enumerate to create headings.

Answer (score 3):

The code is like your:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \centering
  \item First title
  \item Second title
\end{enumerate}
```

That's all here.

**UPDATE**

Maybe I understood what do you need. In my opinion the more simple code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myitem}[1] {\item\mbox{} \begin{flushleft} #1 \end{flushleft} }
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \centering
    \myitem{The first.}
    \myitem{The second.}
  \end{enumerate}   
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:
[image: Screenshot of the second code]

Comment: I have thought about that already, but if I have an enumeration, wich is centered, and I want plain text under this point, wich is not centered, how do I achieve this?